# Unique descompisition of a function as a sum of an isometry and a bounded function.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, analytic-geometry, isometry

I have the following question:
Let $h \colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $h(x)=\Psi(x)+\rho(x)$ with $\Psi$ isometry and $\rho$ a bounded function. Are $\Psi$ and $\rho$ unique in such a way that $h(x)=\Psi(x)+\rho(x)$ ?

My attempt is the following:

Let $\Psi,\varphi$ isometries and $\rho,\phi$ bounded functions such that

$h(x)=\Psi(x)+\rho(x)=\varphi(x)+\phi(x)$

We know we can write any isometry as a descomposition of a rotation and translation (uniques), so

$h(x)=A(x)+t+\rho(x)=B(x)+r+\phi(x)$ with $A, B$ rotations

$A(x)-B(x)=\phi(x)-\rho(x)+r-t$

We know that rotation fix $0$, then

$0=\phi(0)-\rho(0)+r-t$ but I do not know how to finish, also I do not if its true, any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any isometry $\Psi$ is generated by rotation, reflections and translations, namely $\Psi(x)=Ax+b$ where $A\in \mathbb O_n(\mathbb R), b\in \mathbb R^n$. 
Thus if $h=\Psi+\rho$, replacing $\rho$ by a translate of $\rho$, namely $\rho+b$, one can assume that $\Psi$ is linear.

Suppose $$\Psi_1 +\rho_1= \Psi_2+\rho_2$$ 
Then we get $$\Psi_1 - \Psi_2=\rho_2-\rho_1$$
The $RHS$ is the difference of $2$ bounded functions and hence bounded. The $LHS$ is a linear map. So we get $\Psi_1-\Psi_2$ is a linear map which is bounded as a function (please do not confuse this with bounded linear map). This forces $\Psi_1-\Psi_2=0$ and hence $\rho_1=\rho_2$

Thus you do get uniqueness upto a translation.

Comment: Sorry, why $\Psi_1-\Psi_2$ is a linear map and bounded function implies $\Psi_1-\Psi_2=0$?

Comment: Ok I think I get it, suppose there exist a vector $x$ such that $\Psi_1(x)-\Psi_2(x) \neq 0$ then if we choose $\lambda$ a scalar goes to infinite then $\lambda(\Psi_1(x)-\Psi_2(x))$ goes to infinite and that is a contradiction with the fact that function is bounded. Thanks :)